# Scala variable value substitution

Tags: scala

How do I substitute the variable value instead of the variable name ?

Problem description:

*I initially thought to hide the complexity but looks like you might need it to better understand the problem.*

I need to build SQL query dynamically based on Databricks Notebook parameters.

So, I created a config dataframe in the notebook; this notebook has all the possible combinations. Created a function which takes the arguments needed for the dataframe filtering to select the appropriate variable name. These variables are actually the part of select list, or WHERE condition, etc. needed to build the final SQL query.

Config Dataframe:

```
|code|configName|variableName|
|----|-------------|
|ABC|var1|v_var1_name|
|DEF|var2|v_var2_name|
```

Pseudo Code:

```scala
// 1. Function, getVariableName, takes "code" and "configName" (dataframe column value) as arguments to filter on the dataframe and fetches the return value of variableName. As we can see the variableName changes depending the argument passed to the function.

// 2. example-1:
val v_var1_name = "select col1, col2 "
val v_var1 = getVariableName("ABC", var1)

// Output value:
v_sql = "v_select_list"

// Desired output:
v_sql = "select col1, col2 "

// example-2:
val v_sql_filter = "where a.col1 = 'CA' "
val v_sql = getVariableName("DEF")

// Output value:
v_sql = "v_sql_filter"

// Desired value:
v_sql = "where a.col1 = 'CA' "

// NOTE: I cannot embed the sql string into the dataframe column as it can be very big sometimes. It has to be a variable name only.

// 3. Now, building the final SQL query.
// For #2 example-1, 
val sql_final = v_sql + " from table where col1 = 'OR' "

// For #2, example-2,
val sql_final = "select col1 from table" + v_sql_filter
```

Comment: You don't. You use a dictionary or a data structure built for named access. And please, **please** do not interpolate into SQL queries. Use prepared statements. Every reputable SQL library has them. SQL interpolation is one of the most basic security vulnerabilities, and it's incredibly easy to exploit.

Comment: Where is that value coming from? Another table? A third party service? Config file? Environment variable? You have a set of input params and based on that you have a logic to decide which table? Please provide more context to understand your use case.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfect example of a security vulnerability. To reiterate, **never do this**. Some 13-year-old script kiddie will come along and wreck your entire database in five minutes flat. Prepare a statement using your SQL driver. It's the only safe way.

Comment: I'd use a `Map` to store the association. But as others said, be very careful on the usage. This will need extra care to not let people damage your systems because of their inputs.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks for your advice. I used two maps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaston thanks for your input but as Gael mentioned I used two maps to achieve this. Below is the source code (I changed the original code to achieve this)

```
Config Dataframe:
```

```
|code|configName|variableName|
|----|-------------|
|ABC|var1|var1_name|
|DEF|var2|var2_name|
```

Pseudo Code:

```scala
// 1. Function, getVariableName, takes "code" and "configName" (dataframe column value) as arguments to filter on the dataframe and fetches the return value of variableName. As we can see the variableName changes depending the argument passed to the function.

// 2. example-1:
val var1_name = "select col1, col2 "
val var1 = getVariableName("ABC", "var1")

val var2_name = "where a.col1 = 'CA' "
val var2 = getVariableName("DEF", "var2")

val var_map = Map("var1" -> var1, "var2" -> var2)  
val var_sql_map = Map("var1_name" -> var1_name, "var2_name" -> var2_name) 

val var1_value = var_map("var1)
val var2_value = var_map("var2)

val sql_string1 = var_sql_map(var1_value)
val sql_string2 = var_sql_map(var2_value)

println(sql_string1)
println(sql_string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

You can use [String Interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

Config Dataframe

| code | variable_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | v_select_list | col1,col2,col3 |
| DEF | v_sql_filter | col1 = '<value1>' AND col2 = '<value2>' |

```
val columns = getVariableName("ABC")
val conditions = getVariableName("DEF")

val query = s"SELECT $columns WHERE $conditions"
```

---

I don't think that approach is the best. As others said in comments, it could have a lot of security vulnerabilities. Here you have a thread that talks about [spark vulnerabilities considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805876/spark-sql-security-considerations).

Having piece of sql queries saved as string and then execute them without any validation could end in some undesired behaviour. Someone could dump all your data, you could have a condition that doesn't filter anything making you to process tons of data that is not required.

Looks like in `Spark 3.4.0` they added the possibility to execute [sql using named parameters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#sql(sqlText:String,args:java.util.Map%5BString,Any%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) but is annotated as `Experimental`.

`DataSet` has an API where you have call [select](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#select(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method to pass all the columns you want to pick, and also you can call [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#filter(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) method to apply all the conditions you want. You have the possibility to use the ones that accept `Columns` type and see how you can build them based on what you fetch from some other place or pass just a raw string, but I said before, the raw string could not be the best option if that value comes from a user or some dynamic configuration. Unless you know that all that stuff is internal and no one with bad intentions could execute this script, I would suggest to avoid raw strings.